# Is ubuntu 20.04 compatible with raspberry pi 400?

Tags: hardware, linux, ubuntu

I use a usb 3.0 for mass storage (with boot). But my OS (ubuntu 20.04) is very slow. What can I do to make it faster ? (I'm on raspberry pi 400)

Comment: Use the server version rather than desktop...

Comment: Your title and question don't match. You claim you are running it but it is slow, so obviously it is compatible.

Comment: USB3.0 SATA adaptor to a SATA SSD disk which supports USAP as the fastest disk your like todo.

Answer (score 1):

"What can I do to make it faster ?" Install Raspberry Pi OS.

Comment: Raspberry Pi OS will not make the OS run faster.. 32bit OS is slower than Ubuntu 64Bit.

Comment: @SimonBanks It is a common misconception that 64-bit OS are faster; in fact they are usually slower. E.g. Sysbench on Raspberry Pi OS (64-bit) takes 10.0003s vs 8.7858s on Raspberry Pi OS (32-bit). I can't benchmark Ubuntu as it is such a memory hog.

Comment: I've benchmarked Ubuntu on 32 bit and 64 bit..on raspberry pi 4 and CM4 and running a 64bit processor is faster by a minimum  of 10% in all operations.  More depending on the type of operations.

Comment: https://hackaday.com/2020/01/28/raspberry-pi-4-benchmarks-32-vs-64-bits/

Comment: That's ok. I'v found : 5.10.23-1-MANJARO-ARM 64 bit. The most faster OS for raspberry pi 400 that I've tried with USB 3.0.